# Decoding immediate value in call/jmp instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, disassembly

I'm currently working on an Intel x86 disassembler.

And I'm more precisely trying to support CALLs instructions (and JMP naturally), but I have some problem when it comes to decoding them.

Here is my problem, I've the `e8` opcode, which can be `callw` or `call`.
And it's only operand is an immediate value.

It looked pretty simple to implement, until I tried to disassemble: `call 0x12345`.

Which gave:

`e8 41 23 01 00          call   12346 <_main+0x12346>`

I didn't understood why the disassembler converted my  `call 0x12345` into a `call 0x12346`.

Also, the disassembler outputs `call 0x12346` while giving as the instruction in hex format `e8 41 23 01 00`.

And `41 23 01 00 (0x12341)` isn't equal to `0x12345` or even `0x12346`.

After a while, I found that `0x12341` + the size of the instruction (5 bytes) is equal to `0x12346` which doesn't seem absurd.

But I still don't know why it converted my original `0x12345` into a `0x12346`.

I could take that in note and each time add one to the immediate and substract it by 5 bytes but I'll prefer knowing the technical reason behind instead of trying to randomly fix my *problem* to avoid any form of future miscomprehension.

Comment: [`call rel32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) takes a *relative* displacement, relative to the *end* of the instruction.  (Same for an assembler computing a relative displacement in the first place, given an absolute target).  Anything a disassembler prints for an absolute target address is computed from what it thinks the address of the end of the call instruction is, but you haven't shown how you're assembling / disassembling.

Comment: ".. I still don't know why it converted my original .." – it must be something in your code. Which is not supplied in the question. It may be a mystery for ever, then.